# AutoCompleteTextView - Change orientation - Crash on message "IndexOutOfBoundsException" in landscape mode

Tags: android, autocomplete, orientation, landscape-portrait

I'm using AutoCompleteTextView in my app with a custom adapter populated with web service and it works perfect in portrait mode. 
In landscape mode however I have a crash on message "IndexOutOfBoundsException 10 / index -1" when I selected an item after the third.

In landscape mode, items are displayed per 3 items.
I have a crash on message "IndexOutOfBoundsException size 10 index -1" when I selected an item in landscape mode after the third.

In the manifest, I have this line :
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nathalie, welcome to stack overflow, you shall post your code of what you've done so far so we can help you better

Comment: it is fine now for me with :    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi" on my  AutoCompleteTextView element, and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" in manifest on my activity.  Thanks

Comment: with this solution, it isn't still to scroll up and down on my activity :(

Comment: I changed windowSoftInputMode in my activity on event onConfigurationChanged and kept value adjustResize by default in manifest